How to reduce the binary size for FFMPEG library for android application
In my Androdi project I am using the FFmpeg library to extract a thumbnail from a particular video frame (HLS).
I am able to generate the thumbnail successfully but the final APK size increase by 100+ MB, any suggestion on how to reduce the APK size?
I only need the library for generating thumbnail from HLS videos.
I have tried different Packages options mentioned in the FFmpeg library but no major decrease in APK size.
Also any other lightweight library for generating thumbnail will also work.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

The ffmpeg library contains all .so files for multiple CPU architectures. If you don't publish via Google Play (which will provide each device only those libraries it needs) I would reduce the .so files to the armv8-64 architecture and may be x86_64 if you want to allow emulator usage of your app. You can remove (.so) files using gradle packagingOptions.

You can configure ffmpeg to only support the containers and codecs you need, in your case probably hls, mpegts, h264/5 and maybe fmp4 (?). That should reduce the size.

Thanks but I have zero idea of doing that, can you please guide me or share the document link for doing that

Do you even need FFmpeg for this?  Seems like something you could do with the system libraries.

I have tried MediaMetadataRetriever but it does not work for live streams (HLS)
